# Aggregations of transactions between two timestamps by an ID in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trino

I'm trying to calculate velocity aggregations over different time windows for ids in a sql table. I have a table:

```
TABLE transactions (
  transaction_id int,
  customer_id int,
  date Timestamp,
  should_aggregate boolean,
)
```

and i'm trying to create a table with velocity features at the time of the transaction

```
TABLE transaction_velocity (
  transaction_id int,
  customer_id int,
  date Timestamp,
  previous_1hour int,
  previous_1day  int,
  previous_1week int
)
```

For example if we had:

| transaction_id | customer_id | date | should_aggregate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-10 01:00:00 +0000 | true |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-01-10 00:55:00 +0000 | false |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-01-09 00:57:00 +0000 | true |
| 4 | 1 | 2023-01-07 00:57:00 +0000 | false |
| 5 | 2 | 2023-01-10 00:57:00 +0000 | true |

The resulting table would be:

| transaction_id | customer_id | date | previous_1hour | previous_1day | previous_1week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-10 01:00:00 +0000 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-01-09 00:57:00 +0000 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2023-01-10 00:57:00 +0000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Essentially each row is aggregated on past transactions per customer over 3 time windows if it's marked for aggregation. I've considered using partition windowing, but can't figure out how to do that over timestamp.

Comment: What are velocity aggregations? (No sarcasm, I don't understand the term). Your expected results seem to be counts of the records for the same customer within that time range. Is that correct?

Comment: By velocity aggregations I mean at the time of the request, how many transactions had happened in a time window before it. It's the speed of transactions coming into the current transaction.

Comment: Why (1, 1, 3) in the first row? It should be (1, 1, 1) since the other two rows belong to a different group. Or, does this mean that "previous_1week" ignores the subgroups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated, you might be able to do this with some window functions, however I think I might just recommend a self join:

```
SELECT
 t1.transaction_id
 , t1.customer_id
 , t1.date
 , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.date > DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) previous_1hour
 , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.date > DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) previous_1day
 , SUM(CASE WHEN t2.date > DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) previous_1week
FROM transactions t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t2
  ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id AND t2.date < t1.date
WHERE t1.should_aggregate
GROUP BY t1.transaction_id, t1.customer_id, t1.date
```

This simply joins the records with the same `customer_id` and a smaller `date`, and the `sum`s in the `select` count them if the `date` is large enough to be in the interval.

If someone has a simple way of doing this with window functions, sure, use that, but I think the above is pretty enough and easy to follow. (I just can't think of a good way of doing this with window functions, I'm not recommending against that.)

An alternative might be correlated subqueries in the `select`:

```
SELECT
  transaction_id
  , customer_id
  , date
  , (SELECT count(*) FROM transactions t2 WHERE t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id AND t2.date > DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND t2.date < t1.date) previous_1hour
  , (SELECT count(*) FROM transactions t2 WHERE t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id AND t2.date > DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND t2.date < t1.date) previous_1day
  , (SELECT count(*) FROM transactions t2 WHERE t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id AND t2.date > DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND t2.date < t1.date) previous_1week
FROM transactions t1
WHERE should_aggregate
```

You can see both of these options generating your expected output [in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QsD0V0Xw).